# Bloom Filter vs. Hashset

Tags: hash, hashset, bloom-filter

Bloomfilters are often less space efficient than hashsets if the key cardinality is small.

Say we have 20bit keys and a set size of 1024 (10bit). A hashset with 1024 entries nees to store a 10-bit tag in each entry. As a result the size of a hashset is ~10Kbit, with zero chance for false positives.

A bloomfilter with a FP rate of 10^-7 has a size of ~33Kbit (3x larger): https://hur.st/bloomfilter/?n=1000&p=1.0E-7&m=&k=20

I can accept some false positives. Is there a probabilistic data structure that is more space efficient that the two techniques above?

One could try hashing the key

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I think you’ve underestimated the size of your hash set. A hash set holding 20-bit keys needs to store 20 bits per item (each element of the hash set is one of the items being stored), and with 1024 items you’d need a minimum of 20Kb for the hash table just to store the items. That’s ignoring the internal hash table overhead; most hash tables overallocate space in some way. If you’re using something like a linear probing table, your load factor will typically be around 2/3 and so there’s an extra 50% space premium on top of the baseline 20Kb. So something like 20Kb - 30Kb is a good estimate for your space usage here.

Now let’s talk probabilistic data structures. The memory usage for a Bloom filter with false positive rate ε and n items is roughly 1.44n lg ε<sup>-1</sup>, where lg is the binary logarithm (log<sub>2</sub> x).

The main reason your Bloom filter usage is so high here is that with a false positive rate of 10<sup>-7</sup> is set very, very low, which means that each item is going to need a lot of bits to store.

You’ve said that you’re okay with some false positives. If that’s the case, I would first recommend simply increasing your false positive rate. Increasing ε to 10<sup>-2</sup>, for example, would drop your space usage by a factor of 2/7, which would get the space usage down to 10Kb.

Another option would be to use a more modern data structure in place of a Bloom filter. An XOR filter uses 1.23n lg ε<sup>-1</sup> bits, which is an improvement over a Bloom filter. More recent improvements on the XOR filter drops that leading coefficient down to around 1.13. Cuckoo filters use (roughly) 1.08n lg ε<sup>-1</sup> + 3n bits. All of these are better than Bloom filters for an appropriate choice of ε, but as above making ε bigger would still lead to more dramatic savings.

Comment: thanks. I was thinking to use 10bit of the key to index the hash bucket, in this case tag is only 10 bit (for direct mapped). If we use an 8-way set associative we need a 13-bit tag. thanks for the links, very helpful.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. How would you handle multiple 20-bit keys that collide in the same bucket?

Comment: one would need to replace a line in the same set. A random replacement policy does it for free, pseudo-LRU/RRIP costs another 2 bits per line.

Comment: Gotcha. So it’s less a hash set and more of a cache where data loss is okay?